# Alfresco -changed IP now can't login

Tags: alfresco

I had my server's IP address changed and now I can't login to Alfresco share or access server:8080/alfresco

Nothing else has change apart from IP address and an exemption through a firewall. Ports haven't changed.

Attempting to login at server:8080/share gives me:

```
"Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may not be available at this time."
```

And under server:8080/alfresco -

```
HTTP Status 404 - /alfresco 
type Status report

message /alfresco

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Still using these properties in alfresco-global.properties

```
alfresco.context=alfresco
alfresco.host=127.0.0.1
alfresco.port=8080
alfresco.protocol=http

share.context=share
share.host=127.0.0.1
share.port=8080
share.protocol=http
```

Part of today's catalina log is below. The IP change happened around 11.30-40am.. Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
Jun 04, 2014 11:29:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 04, 2014 11:29:51 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 04, 2014 11:29:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jun 04, 2014 11:29:58 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 04, 2014 11:29:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 04, 2014 11:29:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 04, 2014 11:29:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.27 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.29
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.27 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.29
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.27 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.29
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.27 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.29
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.27 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.29
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1610 ms
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jun 04, 2014 12:04:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/jo1hpc/alfresco-4.2.e-2/apache-tomcat/webapps/share.war
Jun 04, 2014 12:05:24 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [22,999] milliseconds.
Jun 04, 2014 12:05:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/jo1hpc/alfresco-4.2.e-2/apache-tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/jo1hpc/alfresco-4.2.e-2/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/jo1hpc/alfresco-4.2.e-2/apache-tomcat/webapps/host-manager
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/jo1hpc/alfresco-4.2.e-2/apache-tomcat/webapps/docs
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/jo1hpc/alfresco-4.2.e-2/apache-tomcat/webapps/examples
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/jo1hpc/alfresco-4.2.e-2/apache-tomcat/webapps/manager
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jun 04, 2014 12:09:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 296854 ms
Jun 04, 2014 12:29:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
```

Comment: The messages in the catalina.out are pretty obvious. What have you done so far to resolve this?

Comment: haven't done anything really, I don't really know what the messages mean.

Comment: my best gues: you didn't fix name resolution on the host. maybe in the hosts your hostname is still registered with the old ip?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like startup is failing:

> SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.27 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.29
>
> SEVERE: Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors

Try updating Tomcat Native: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi

Comment: I feel silly, I hadn't updated my /etc/hosts file with the new IP address in!